# Excluding an element from nth-child pattern

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say I have these elements:

```
<li class="class1">content</li>
<li class="class1">content</li>
<li class="class1 class2">content</li>
<li class="class1">content</li>
<li class="class1">content</li> <!-- I want nth-child(4n) to select this-->
<li class="class1">content</li>
<li class="class1">content</li>
<li class="class1">content</li>
```

I want to use a `.class1:nth-child(4n)` to select every 4th element, but if an element has BOTH `class1` and `class2` I don't want it to be included in the "every 4th" counting--I just want it to be ignored.

I've tried `.class1:not(.class2):nth-child(4n)`, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Here's a JSFiddle for experimentation: http://jsfiddle.net/jWxb6/2/

Comment: Did you try reversing that?
    .class1:nth-child(4n):not(.class2)

Comment: Yeah...no luck. Added a JSFiddle for experimentation.

Comment: The one you want to select is the 5th and not the fourth so with 4n it will never work.

Comment: Right, I was hoping for the selector to essentially say, "For every fourth occurrence of elements only containing class1"--or at least something similar to that.

Comment: I don't think it is achievable with pure css

Comment: Since n-th child select all of the children under the parent, even .class3:nth-child(4n) alone will still select the 4th list item

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't realize that at first, now I feel silly. They should really add a :nth-of-class() selector.

Comment: @Pete the best you can do is not to select the 4th one if it has a certain class `.class1:nth-child(3n):not(.class2)` applied to your original code will do that but that's about it with pure css

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`nth-child` selector just counts any child nodes, so `.class1:nth-child(4)` means 'element that is the 4th child of the container *and* has `class1` class', not 'the 4th element with that class in the container'. The `nth-of-type` selector can select only elements of the specific type (tag name), so you can, e.g., count `dt` elements separately from `dd` elements in a `dl` list. There is `nth-child(4 of .class1)` syntax in [CSS Selectors 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#the-nth-child-pseudo) draft, but it's currently supported [only](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-nth-child-of) in the latest versions of Safari.

With the CSS supported by most browsers, you can 'reset the counter' after the element you want to exclude from counting and 'start the new counter' for the remaining part of the list:

```
.class1:nth-child(4n) {
    list-style-type: circle;
}

.class1.class2, .class2 ~ .class1:nth-child(4n) {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
.class2 ~ .class1:nth-child(4n + 1) {
    list-style-type: circle;
}
```

and so on (see [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jWxb6/11/)).

Alternatively, you can change the markup and use different tags instead of classes and `nth-of-type`.

Comment: `nth-match` has been dropped; it's been rolled into nth-child for Selectors Level 4.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to accomplish is not possible with pure css in my knowledge. (I'd be happy if I'd be proven wrong.). However, you can accomplish what you want simply with jQuery. Here's a working example:

http://jsbin.com/fumeq/2/

Comment: ... or javascript.  Loading a copy of jQuery (if it's not already loaded) to solve this issue is like using a wrecking ball for a paperweight.

Comment: Of course. What I want to point out here is that it can't be accomplished with pure css. Otherwise, as you say, loading jQuery just for this case is completely not necessary and good at all.

Answer (score 0):

another approach is - add the elements as hidden elements you additionally need. Referring to your jsfiddle, that means you could solve the problem like this:

```
.hide{
  display:none;
}

.class2 {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

.class1:nth-child(4n):not(.class2) {
border: 1px solid red;
}

<ul>
    <li class="class1">content</li>
    <li class="class1">content</li>
      <li class="hide">helper</li>
      <li class="hide">helper</li>
      <li class="hide">helper</li>
    <li class="class1 class2">content</li>
    <li class="class1">content</li>
    <li class="class1">content</li>
    <li class="class1">content</li>
    <li class="class1">content</li>
    <li class="class1">content</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not a direct answer, but would it work if you just overrode the previous CSS styling, i.e. ?

```
.class1:nth-child(4n) { color: red; }
.class2 { color: inherit !important; }
```

Comment: This still selects the 4th and not the 5th as the OP wanted

Comment: I don't see any mention of 5th?

Comment: The first block of code, in the comments `I want nth-child(4n) to select this` the one that's pointed to is the 5th not the fourth

Comment: @Huangism If you read the text below the block of code, you will not observe the OP explicitly stating that he/she wants the 5th element to be selected instead of the 4th. The OP explicitly states that "if an element has BOTH class1 and class2 I don't want it to be included in the "every 4th" counting--I just want it to be ignored.". Nowhere is there a mention of 5th element "needs to be selected". That seems to be what you have inferred not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny there is no mention of the 5th element however it is the one that's needed. He's not going to get to the fifth one when he is doing 4n. 4n will always select the 4th, classes in this case don't even matter

Answer (score -1):

Based on what I have understood, you want to select(and style) every fourth element in this listing. BUT if any of these selected elements have an additional class (named 'class2' or for that matter, whatever class name) attached to it, then you don't want to apply any styling onto it.

You can do this with pure CSS. Instead of using the following CSS selector:

```
.class1:not(.class2):nth-child(4n) {
    color: Blue;
}
```

you could use:

```
li[class="class1"]:nth-child(4n) {
    color:Orange;
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLpb5/

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Satwik. Actually, what I want is for elements with class2 not to be counted at all. As in, they aren't considered one of the elements that the every 4th rule is counting through.

Comment: @Huangism I did not. I used the link I provided in my answer.