# reset CSS :nth-of-type counter

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am using a WP events plugin that creates a list of events in the following format:-

```css
.event-list .event {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 0;
    background: #eee;
}

span.month {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.event-list div.event:nth-of-type(3n){
margin-left:5%;
}

.event-list div.event:nth-of-type(3n+1){
margin-left: 0;
clear: both;
}

.event-list div.event:nth-of-type(3n+2){
margin-left:5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="event-list">
<span class="month">January</span>
<div class="event">Event 1</div>
<div class="event">Event 2</div>
<div class="event">Event 3</div>
<div class="event">Event 4</div>
<span class="month">February</span>
<div class="event">Event 5</div>
<div class="event">Event 6</div>
<div class="event">Event 7</div>
<div class="event">Event 8</div>
<div class="event">Event 9</div>
<div class="event">Event 10</div>
</div>
```

I would like the nth-of-type counter to reset after every span element so that the columns work no matter the number of events that month. I have tried using the tilde ~ selector (as was suggested here [Excluding an element from nth-child pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770593/excluding-an-element-from-nth-child-pattern) http://jsfiddle.net/jWxb6/11/) but I can't for the life of me get it to work. I would like to do it without using JS/JQuery if i can but that is an option if there is no pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not considering something more simple to achieve this. Here is and idea using flexbox and without the need to use complex selectors as what you want to do won't be possible with your actual HTML structure.

```css
.event-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.event-list .event {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

span.month {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="event-list">
  <span class="month">January</span>
  <div class="event">Event 1</div>
  <div class="event">Event 2</div>
  <div class="event">Event 3</div>
  <div class="event">Event 4</div>
  <span class="month">February</span>
  <div class="event">Event 5</div>
  <div class="event">Event 6</div>
  <div class="event">Event 7</div>
  <div class="event">Event 8</div>
  <div class="event">Event 9</div>
  <div class="event">Event 10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it is certainly better than the implementation I currently have. The only issue this has is that when there are 2 events on a row they justify to each side rather than to the left like they did with my float: left method (Try moving the february span down 1 event)

Answer (score -1):

You just need to wrap each month's events in a new div so that the counter will reset to 1 inside of the parent.

```css
.event-list .event {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 0;
    background: #eee;
}

span.month {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.event-list .month_wrapper div.event:nth-of-type(3n){
margin-left:5%;
}

.event-list .month_wrapper div.event:nth-of-type(3n+1){
margin-left: 0;
clear: both;
}

.event-list .month_wrapper div.event:nth-of-type(3n+2){
margin-left:5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="event-list">
<div class="month_wrapper">
<span class="month">January</span>
<div class="event">Event 1</div>
<div class="event">Event 2</div>
<div class="event">Event 3</div>
<div class="event">Event 4</div>
</div>
<div class="month_wrapper">
<span class="month">February</span>
<div class="event">Event 5</div>
<div class="event">Event 6</div>
<div class="event">Event 7</div>
<div class="event">Event 8</div>
<div class="event">Event 9</div>
<div class="event">Event 10</div>
</div>
</div>
```